# Is it bad SEO to use sessionStorage to show/hide home page content for a "splash page"?

Tags: javascript, css, seo, hidden, session-storage

Our boss recently asked our dev team to build what he calls a "splash page" for the home page of our web site. Not the stand-alone, redirecting splash page of old. Instead, a home-page visitor would at first see nothing but a hard-sell, call-to-action "splash" message with two buttons: a `mailto` link and an "Enter Site" button. If the "Enter Site" button is clicked, the hard-sell message goes away the the "regular" home-page content is revealed.

The solution devised by a team member is to have a `#hardsell` div and a `#main` content div (which includes the site header and navigation). Both divs have `display:none` set with inline CSS.

Visibility between the two divs is toggled using `sessionStorage`. This avoids having to set a cookie.

```
function splashCheck() {
    var readValue = sessionStorage['myvariable'];
    if (readValue === "splash") {
        $("#main").css( "display", "block" );
    } else {
        $("#hardsell").css( "display", "block" );
            var myVariable = "splash";
            sessionStorage['myvariable'] = myVariable;
        }
}
splashCheck()
```

This is admirably simple, but I am concerned about two things:

1. Having `display: none` on the `#main` and `#hardsell` divs means there's no visible content until that `splashCheck()` function fires. You see nothing if javascript is disabled.
2. SEO: What will Google bots and other crawlers see on this page? Nothing? (Bad!) Only the `#hardsell` content? (Also bad!) The `#main` content? (Preferred!) Both sets of content? (Acceptable!)

I cannot find a definitive answer as to what Google will and will not crawl in this case. Google bots will supposedly crawl hidden content like accordions, but Google docs also say that bots "may have" issues with dynamic hidden sections.

Are my concerns baseless? Is there a way to do this with sessionStorage that lets Google crawl the `#main` content while showing visitors just the `#hardsell` on initial visit?

Comment: Disable your CSS and JavaScript, and refresh the page. That's what Google will see.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier exactly!

Comment: @EmielZuurbier — Your suggestion shows a page in which the content of both divs is readable, which is comforting. It still concerns me that if JS is turned off, a visitor will see nothing, but how many people disable javascript these days?

Comment: I guess it's safe to say that the percentage is quite small. However, for compatibility sake, you could check if JavaScript is enabled and then use your splash screen. If JS is disabled, then make it accessible to use without the splash screen. That way everybody can use the site.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier — Brilliant! That's the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my poorly composed question is "not bad if JavaScript detection is leveraged." As @EmielZuurbier suggested in comment on the initial question:

> for compatibility sake, you could check if JavaScript is enabled and then use your splash screen. If JS is disabled, then make it accessible to use without the splash screen. That way everybody can use the site.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be formulated to: "How does javascript content affect SEO".
The same question is often asked when working with SPA such as react or angular

As @Emiel Zuurbier comments, "Disable your CSS and JavaScript, and refresh the page. That's what Google will see.". Is not 100% correct, do you really think googles crawlers cannot read javascript content? We'll kind of, js content makes it hard for crawlers to read content.

To answer your question:

> Is it bad SEO to use sessionStorage to show/hide home page content for a “splash page”?
> Sessionstorage, no.
> Javascript dynamic content, yes.

I suggest you read this article

[https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blog/spa-seo-mission-impossible.html#:~:text=SPAs%20are%20not%20inherently%20friendly,play%20nicely%20with%20Google's%20crawler](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blog/spa-seo-mission-impossible.html#:%7E:text=SPAs%20are%20not%20inherently%20friendly,play%20nicely%20with%20Google%27s%20crawler).

> According to SEO expert Barry Adams, React-based SPAs (and other JavaScript-based SPAs), don’t play nicely with Google’s crawler.

Comment: You're correct; my statement does not fully cover what a search bot sees or not as they've become better in handling JS powered websites. However in the case of OP, that is not the kind of functionality the site has.

Comment: Thanks, Stanley, but while React/Angular/SPAs have some bearing on the issue of visibility, the site at issue is just plain old files, with one bit of JS modifying the home page. @Emiel Zuurbier 's suggestion above renders a page that shows the content of both divs, so if that's an accurate representation of what Google will crawl, I guess I am less concerned about it, although it still bugs me that an actual visitor with javascript off will see nothing.

Comment: @divvuk aha, that makes sense! To be fair, anyone browsing the internet without javascript wouldn't be able to see much

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

> Once the HTML is being served to the web crawlers (even if you are
> hiding certain parts with CSS) you should be fine and will have your
> pages indexed.

If it will be built with a single-page application framework (SPA), I would suggest you go for a server-side rendering (SSR) implementation instead say with NextJS or Nuxt, which will serve actual HTML content the web crawlers can index.

The bottom line is once you are serving up the content in pure HTML, which is [crawlable](https://www.semrush.com/blog/what-are-crawlability-and-indexability-of-a-website/) you are fine.

There are plans to make SPAs indexable in the [long run](https://www.magnolia-cms.com/blog/spa-seo-mission-impossible.html), but at this time of writing it is better to stick with the most effective (Plain HTML with the metas and SEO related metas included) or an SSR implementation.

SPA  (NO HTML content for web crawlers)
[image]

SSR (Specifically this is with Next) - Content for web crawlers
[image]

Vanilla, HTML/CSS/JS - Content for web crawlers
[image]

Comment: Thanks, King David Gyimah, but this is just a little old multipage web site; we've no plans to build this as an SPA.